# how to do "messages should reach the app inbox before it going to native" in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast

I'm developing one messaging app, in which the incoming messages will be stored in its own inbox. But it is storing in both native message inbox & app inbox same time.
How to prevent messages reaching to native inbox before reaching to the app?

Comment: Are you sure you want to stop it from reaching the native inbox?  Any other app that tries to read SMSes will be looking at the native inbox-  you'd break them all.

Answer (score 1):

Call `abortBroadcast()` in the BroadcastReceiver when you're done adding the message to your inbox. Make sure that your receiver's priority is higher than that of the other messaging app.